# Pass props to different components in react

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-props

Just having troubles, sorry for the noob question, but i can't seem to log the props results in the DisplayData.js file. I am trying to pass the SearchStockResult state to the DisplatData.js file... I have tried to console log the data property with no luck. Not to sure what is going on. Excuse the naming conventions as I had just changed it from a stock search to a crypto search.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import DisplayData from './DisplayData';

export default class stockSearch extends Component {
   state = {
       searchResult: '',
   }

   componentDidMount = () => {

    fetch(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH,IOT&tsyms=USD`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        this.setState({ searchResult: data });
        console.log(this.state.searchResult);

    });
}


    render() {
        const {data} = this.state;

        return (
            <form>
            <label>
              Name:
              <input type="text" name="query" />
            </label>
            <button>Search Crypto</button>

            <DisplayData results={data} />

          </form>




        )
    }
}



import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class DisplayData extends Component {

    dataResults = (props) => {

        console.log('from data results', props.results);

    }



    render() {
        return (
            <div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not calling the function on the class component. Try adding this.dataResults() in the render method of DisplayData. Or you can just put console.log(this.props) directly into the render method. React will call lifecycle methods and the render method when props change. Custom methods don't get called.

Comment: `console.log(this.state.searchResult);` has got no meaning cuz react setState is not synchronous.

Comment: inside your `DisplayData` component, you didn't call `dataResults` function. Even y our `dataResults` function is very weird. What's your desired goal?

Comment: @Will it logs when i log this.props but it says its undefined in the console.

Comment: to be able to log the data in the console on the displaydata component @O.o

Comment: it won't work as you want, use`setState` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make few corrections:

- State update is async. So pass a call back function if you want to print it
- in StockSearch component, you need to destructure `searchResult` from state (not data)
- In DisplayData component use `this.props`. Also call your function(dataResults) in render method so that it is called and rendered

Working copy of your [code is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stock-search-wzvqo?file=/src/StockSearch.js)

**StockSearch Component**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DisplayData from "./DisplayData";

export default class StockSearch extends Component {
  state = {
    searchResult: ""
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch(
      `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH,IOT&tsyms=USD`
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ searchResult: data }, () => {
          console.log("api result", this.state.searchResult);
        });
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { searchResult } = this.state;
    return (
      <form>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" name="query" />
        </label>
        <button>Search Crypto</button>

        <DisplayData results={searchResult} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

**DisplayData Component**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class DisplayData extends Component {
  dataResults = () => {
    console.log("from data results", this.props.results);
  };

  render() {
    this.dataResults() // just to print
    return <div>{return <div>{JSON.stringify(this.props.results)}</div>;}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: great thanks, is there another way you can display results with just using this.props.results? ie without having to use the callback function

Comment: yes, in your `DisplayData` component's render function simply use, simply use `return <div>{JSON.stringify(this.props.results)}</div>;` ... i will update the answer and codesandbox.... if all good pls accept the answer .thanks